# Traveling slower by traveling in opposite direction as the Earth rotates

Tags: general-relativity, reference-frames, time, time-dilation, observers

I know that if I were to travel fast, the time would pass by fast for me. But if I were to travel fast in the opposite direction of the earths rotation while I'm still on earth, would the time pass by slower for me?
If it would, does that mean that you must consider the solar systems movement and maybe the galaxys movement (what do I know) when calculating time dilation?
I hope you understand my question.

Comment: This was first realized as a significant experiment in 1971: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment.

Comment: It would be helpful to distinguish time dilation as a relativistic phenomenon and changes in the measured time according to the geographic conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In special relativity (things are a bit different in general relativity) time dilation is always relative. There is no such thing as an absolute velocity so there is no such thing as an absolute time dilation.

If you are travelling relative to me at some speed $v$ then the relative rate at which I observe time passing for you is:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1 -\frac{v^2}{c^2}} $$

Note that $v$ appears in this equation only as $v^2$ so it doesn't matter whether $v$ is positive or negative because the square is always positive. Note also that the right hand side is always less than or equal to one so:

$$ d\tau \le dt $$

and I always observe your time to be flowing more slowly than mine.

The velocity at which the galaxy is moving doesn't come into the calculation because the velocity of the galaxy affects you and I equally. It is only our **relative** velocity that affects the time dilation.

Comment: I understand. But I don't really understand it to 100%.
If we have two persons, A and B, of exactly the same age. A is at rest on earth while B is traveling in an airplane in the earths rotation speed in the reversed direction of earths rotation. So B is really staying still above earth, only following earths path around the sun. From A's perspective, B is moving. But from B's perspective, A is moving.
Is A or B moving? Who will be the oldest of them?  Why?